# Problem Installing aircrack-ng

Tags: software-installation, aircrack-ng

When I run: `sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng`

It gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fern-wifi-cracker : Depends: macchanger but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: subversion but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python-qt4 (>= 4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python-scapy (>= 2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version, what PPA's you have?

Comment: Did you try to update the repository and clean the cache or use the -f (force) option of the apt command? You can also try this: apt-get install --fix-missing

Comment: my version of Ubuntu is 16.4 lts